# Cypress intercept not finding fixture file

Tags: cypress

```
  cy.intercept('POST', '/api/create_payment_intent', {
    fixture: 'payment_intent.json', // fixture file with mocked response
  }).as('createPaymentIntent');
```

`payment_intent.json` file exists at `cypress/fixtures/` directory filled with valid json.

Error:

```
[1] [1]      Error: An error was thrown while processing a network event: A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:
[1] [1] 
[1] [1] > cypress/fixtures/payment_intent.json
[1] [1] > cypress/fixtures/payment_intent.json{{extension}}
[1] [1] 
[1] [1] Cypress looked for these file extensions at the provided path:
[1] [1] 
[1] [1] > .json, .js, .coffee, .html, .txt, .csv, .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tif, .tiff, .zip
[1] [1] 
[1] [1] Provide a path to an existing fixture file.
[1] [1] 
[1] [1] Because this error occurred during a `before each` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: `Neo4j Aura Console - Common`
[1] [1]   Error: A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:
[1] [1]   
[1] [1]   > cypress/fixtures/payment_intent.json
[1] [1]   > cypress/fixtures/payment_intent.json{{extension}}
[1] [1]   
[1] [1]   Cypress looked for these file extensions at the provided path:
```

Hoe does one debug this when I have done exactly what the documentation has stated?

Comment: Just a wild guess here, is the .json extension text written in caps?

Comment: @AlapanDas it is not :/ This is driving me bonkers. I am doing exactly what the documentation says to do and yet it still does not find it :(

Comment: Can you provide your exact file structure? My best guess is that while the file may be at `cypress/fixtures/file`, the `cypress.json` file might be located elsewhere that causes some _weirdness_

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was caused by this line in my cypress.config.ts:

```
    fixturesFolder: 'fixtures',
```

After removing this line and restarting cypress, my fixtures got found :)

Comment: It's not a bug! It means that you need to put your files into that folder. In this case, put your files into the "fixtures" folder. This will be your relative directory for your files. Mention the file path relative to this folder in your code.